# C: why my output isn't rounding up using the round() function in math.h?

Tags: c, rounding

I'm writing a grayscale function and I'm using `round()` to round the average of RGB colours but when testing it the round function doesn't round up answers > x.5 instead it rounds everything down.

I have tried changing my int avg to float avg and using the `round()`, didn't work. I tried using `roundf()`, didn't work. when values of red, green and blue are 27, 28, 28 for example I get avg 27 instead of the correct 28.

My code:

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int avg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            avg = round((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 3);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avg;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = avg;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = avg;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is `RGBTRIPLE` containing integer values? If so, then you have an integer division there, which is truncating the fractional par, and rounding it afterwards has no point.

Comment: It looks like you're doing integer math, not floating.  So there are no results in the range [0.5, 1) to round up.  Try changing it to `avg = round(((double)image[i][j].rgbtRed + …`

Comment: Assuming that's the standard `RGBTRIPLE` typedef, `rgbtRed`/`rgbtGreen`/`rgbtBlue` are all `BYTE` data, so that summation and division all occurs as integers. The result of the division will be truncated. The summation will also overflow if `red+green+blue > 255` – perhaps cast them to `float` first before summing.

Comment: RGBTRIPLE contains uint8_t bytes

Comment: does that mean I have to convert all rgbRed, Green and Blue to floats before averaging them ?

Comment: @motto The summation won't overflow, as the operands will be promoted to `int`

Comment: also it won't overflow because that's the average of numbers that won't exceed 255 each

Comment: You can simply divide by `3.0` instead of by `3`. Better yet stay away from floating point calculation and do the rounding yourself by analyzing the difference between `((r+g+b) / 3) * 3` and `r+g+b`

Comment: @steve summit Excuse me, I'm a newbie in coding and this is from CS50 course so I didn't quite get what you did with putting (double) before the integer value of image[i][j].rgbtRed ?

Comment: In the real world you would use different weights for each of the RGB components to match human brightness perception. Typically, something like `0.299*red+0.587*green+0.114*blue`.

Comment: Putting `(double)` before the integer value is a type-cast operation that explicitly converts the integer value to `double`.

Comment: @user75470 The expression `(double)image[i][j].rgbtRed` is a *cast*, which converts the `rgbtRed` value to type `double`.  Then (by the rules of C) since one of the operands being added is of type `double`, they're all converted to and added using type `double`.  Then, since the numerator of the division is a `double`, the denominator (3) is converted to double, and a double-precision floating-point division is performed also, which is the key.  (But as other answers and comments have pointed out, this isn't the only way to do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> round((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 3)
> ```

The values you're adding together are all integers. You're then dividing by an integer. The result is an integer before `round` is ever called. When `round` is called, `27` becomes `27.0`, but that just rounds back to `27`.

In your example, 27 + 28 + 28 = 83. 83 / 3 is 27.666...7. But integer math doesn't consider the fractional part so you get 27.

Simple solution: divide by a floating point number.

```
round((image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 3.0)
```

You will now get a floating point number back from the division which can be rounded.

Comment: thank you, simple solution and simple explanation for a beginner

Answer (score 2):

In C, operations are performed using a type that depends on the operands. For integer operands, an integer type is used.

In `(image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 3`, all of the operands are integers, so an integer type (`int` in this case) is used for the arithmetic. The fact that this expression is a subexpression to `round`, which takes a `double`, does not affect evaluation of this subexpression. This subexpression is evaluated using `int` arithmetic, and then the result is converted to `double` to pass to `round`.

It is not necessary to use `round` to round the average. Since the values are all non-negative integers, their sum has a remainder of 0, 1, or 2 modulo 3. If you simply add 1 to the sum before dividing by 3, you will get a rounded result:

```
avg = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + 1) / 3;
```

Comment: I think your solution works with this equation only with 3 variables and doesn't target the source of my problems ( not using 3.0 to get a float answer ) but still thank you for your answer

Comment: @user75470: This works in general. The number of variables added is not relevant. The divisor is relevant. In general, we can calculate x rounded to an integer with trunc(x+½), where the function trunc removes the fraction part of a number, as integer division does. So trunc(p/q+½) calculates p/q rounded to an integer. And trunc(p/q+½) equals trunc((p+q/2) / q). For integers p and q, this is equivalent to trunc((p + trunc(q/2)) / q). Hence, for q = 3, we have trunc((p + trunc(q/2) / q) = trunc((p+1)/q), so we can just compute (p+1) / q using integer arithmetic…

Comment: … For q = 4, 5, or 6, for example, we would use +2, +2, and +3 instead of +1. Or it could be written as `(p + q/2) / q` for a variable q. (There are some issues about whether we want to round up or down at exactly ½. Some other rounding choices can be implemented by adjusting the arithmetic.) Generally, it is preferable to stay with integer arithmetic, because processors typically have a performance penalty for floating-point arithmetic, particularly division.